# How to style the current submenu item in Umbraco with razor script

Tags: razor, menu, umbraco

I have the following code that creates a submenu based on current document. The document has children, which I use to build a submenu.

How do I check when I am on a current item? I want to style a an item on the submenu when that item is the current one.

I know I can do `if (Model.Id == page.Id)` to find the current item but this does not work
with Documents.

This is the code I want to modify.

```
@foreach (var node in new Document(999).Children)
{
    <li>@node.Id</a>
        @{ var mychildren = node.Children;
           if (mychildren.Count() > 0)
           {
            <ul>
                <li>@node.id</a></li>
                @foreach (var snode in mychildren)
                {
                    <li>@snode.id</a></li>
                }
            </ul>  
        }
    </li>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use DynamicNode instead of Document, then use a helper to check for and add the class? Example:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var node in new Library.NodeNyId(999).Children)
{
    <li@getClasses(node)><a href="@node.NiceUrl">@node.Name</a></li>
    @{
        var mychildren = node.Children;
        if (mychildren.Count() > 0)
        {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var snode in mychildren)
            {
                <li@getClasses(snode)><a href="@snode.NiceUrl">@snode.Name</a></li>
            }
        </ul> 
        }
    }
    </li>
    }
}
</ul>

@helper getClasses(dynamic node)
{
    string classes = "";

    if (Model.Id == node.Id)
    {
        classes = " class=\"active\"";
    }

    @Html.Raw(classes);
}
```

(The Library.NodeById method returns a DynamicNode object.)